# How to reject extra characters entered by the user?

Tags: javascript, input, maxlength

In my HTML, I have an array of inputs. The user should be allowed to enter only one character in each. Here is its HTML:

`<input class = "green" type="text" maxlength="1" />`

The CSS for this is as follows:

```
input {
    font: 1.5em "Times New Roman", Times, serif; 
    width:0.9em; height: 0.9em;
    text-align:center; }
.green { 
    color: green; }
```

If the user enters a character and then tries to enter another, nothing should happen. However, in my design the user can enter any number of characters, even though the earlier characters are pushed to the left and only the last character is visible. When the focus leaves the input field, all extra characters disappear and only the first input character remain. How can I make sure that when the user tries to enter additional characters, they are ignored and nothing happens?

Comment: _"in my design the user can enter any number of characters"_: in your design the inputs will [only allow one character](https://jsfiddle.net/9rLvsu20/). Your markup is working as it should.

Comment: Thank you Andy! Yes, when I switched to Chrome, it behaved as it should. The problem I described was with the Silk browser on Amazon Fire 8. Is there a way to assure the same behavior on each browser?

Comment: Not sure. It looks like SB _should_ support `maxlength` but I'm having trouble finding out release history/HTML5 compatibility for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it what you need?

```js
function go(v){
    if (v.value.length==0){
    return true;
  }
    return false;
}
```

```html
<input class = "green" type="text" maxlength="1" onkeydown="return go(this)"/>
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. BTW, originally I started with HTML you proposed (onkeydown) to analyze user's input (not to limit its length), but then I read that it is deprecated and I switched to addEventListener for keydown as a more modern way to handle the event. This switch created several problems, and I would like to go back to onkeydown. Is it true that it is depreciated? I am new to stackoverflow and I am not sure whether it is ok to ask you here or it is more appropriate to generate a new question? Thanks anyway.

Comment: Would you tell me the source of the onkeydown event is deprecated?

Comment: No, I do not remember the source, I am returning to JavaScript after a long interruption, from the times when tables were used for page design, and I am overwhelmed by new features and even more so by the number of exceptions to these features. 
Yesterday, for example, I saw this warning: “Warning: A third approach for setting event handlers using HTML onevent attributes is not recommended! They inflate the markup and make it less readable and harder to debug. For more information see Inline event handlers.” This is from:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/Event_handlers